# AngularJS почему $watch не проверяет значение переменной?

Tags: angularjs

Быть может я не правильно понимаю, как работает $watch, но у меня не получается проверить значение переменной и если переменная получила определенное значение (к примеру 2), то сбросить это значение в 0.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Online Test</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);


        app.controller("myClick", function($scope)
        {       
            $scope.foo = 0;

            $scope.$watch('foo', function(newval, oldval)
            {
                if($scope.foo = 2)
                {
                    $scope.foo = 0;
                }
            console.log($scope.foo); // почему-то в лог ничего не пишется.

            });

        }); 
        </script>
    </head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myClick">
        <button ng-click="foo = foo + 1"> Click me </button>
        <p>{{foo}}</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Сейчас происходит то, что при клике значение foo продолжает инкрементироваться, а не сбрасываться на 0 при достижении двух.

Еще не совсем понимаю назначение `newval, oldval` эти переменные хранят в себе старое и новое значение в скоупе к которому могу обратиться?

Плюс такой вопрос. Как быть, если мне нужно мониторить вложенную в JSON переменную (к примеру второй уровень вложенности `[]`). Нужно через forEach все обходить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправьте это: `if($scope.foo = 2)`. Должно быть `if($scope.foo == 2)`. Хотя я бы написал `if($scope.foo >= 2)`.

Вот исправный код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Online Test</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
        app.controller("myClick", function($scope) {
            $scope.foo = 0;

            $scope.$watch('foo', function(newval, oldval) {
                if (newval == 2) {
                    $scope.foo = 0;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myClick">
        <button ng-click="foo = foo + 1"> Click me</button>
        <p>{{ foo }}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

На счет `newval` и `oldval` - это значение отслеживаемой переменной после изменения и до изменения соответсвенно. Обратите внимание что для считывания значения я использовал именно `newval`. Не нужно читать значение из `$scope.foo`. Но изменение мы записываем именно в `$scope.foo`.

По второму вопросу: для отслеживания вложенных структур можно применить 2 способа. Допустим у вас есть такой обьект:

```
$scope.foo = {a: 0};
```

вы можете следить за измене а так:

```
$scope.$watch('foo.a', function(new_val) { ... });
```

При любом изменении a в `new_val` окажется ее значение.

Для отслеживания более сложных структур можно сделать так:

```
$scope.$watch('foo', function(new_val) { ... }, true);
```

`true` в качестве третьего параметра `$watch` заставит следит его за изменением любой вложенной части и в `new_val` у вас будет вся измененная структура `foo`

Comment: Спасибо, а обязательно ли писать именно `function(newval, oldval)` и нельзя ли написать `function($scope)` и потом просто проверить `if($scope.foo == 2)` ?

Comment: Ни в коем случае. Я обычно пишу так:

    `$scope.$watch('foo', function(foo) { if (foo == 2) { ... } });`

так как старое значение переменной бывает нужно мне редко, новое просто передаю в функцию с тем именем, что и в scope

Comment: А как мне дотянуться до полнй `isSelected` http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?1zu0yp80gfp1

Мне нужно его проверять на предмет не было ли в нем изменений. Такое возможно? Можно ли как то еще `id` выцеплять, чтобы было понятно какое поле было изменено. Пока `id` не обязательно т.к. главное сейчас научиться определять были ли изменения в полях `isSelected`

Comment: В таком случае вам нужно дописать в `$watch` третий параметр `true` как я писал выше. Тогда в функции вы получите старое и новое значение всего массива, и уже сможете искать там различия. Напишите если нужно рассказать как.

Comment: еще стоит дополнить, что не рекомендуется изменять отслеживаемое значение внутри обработчика, потому что в некоторых случаях это может привести к бесконечному digest циклу.